# Ubuntu Audio device not detected

Tags: audio, ubuntu-11.10

I have a Dell Optiplex 780 running Ubuntu 11.10. Recently I had to hard reset that PC. After that restart, my audio device was no longer detected. Previously, audio had worked fine. The audio/speaker icon in the right hand corner cannot change volume as no audio device is detected.

The sound card is provided by the on-board Intel ICH-10 chipset.
`lspci` gives:
`00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)`

I tried logging in to both my own user account, as well as root. No audio device is detected. What are my options to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: You could try "lspci" in the terminal emulator and look for anything listed as "audio" to determine your soundcard type.

Comment: @washbow thanks. Will do it and let know. Any further pointers.

Comment: lspci -v listed the sound card as : 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)  Does this mean, its the driver which could be unloaded for some reason. Now which is the driver snd or alsa ?

Comment: please post the output of "dpkg -l | grep alsa". Did you run an update just before you lost sound?

Comment: also does "lspci -v" give details of the kernel modules in use?

Comment: @washbow Looking lspci -v for modules it says: "Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel  Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel"

Comment: just clutching at straws but try "sudo alsa force-reload"